# PnP.js: how to get SharePoint custom lookup column value/title for files under a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I have files in SharePoint that have a custom lookup column referencing a list "Document Status".

Using PnP.js, I can get the files under a folder

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/mylib/docs").files.expand('ListItemAllFields').get();
```

It only returns the ID column of the "Document Status" list, but I want to get the Title column of the list. I know probably I can iterate through each file and do another query to get the Title of the lookup value. Is there a better way to get the column(s) of the lookup list? Are there any SharePoint settings I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  could expand the property like this:

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/doc2").files.expand('ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText').get()
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that helps you. Please accept my answer and upvote it if it helps :)